# How can I make the "References" into Sans Serif

Tags: fonts, bibliographies, cross-referencing

Here's my current code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\title{\textbf{\textsf{Title}}}
\author{\textbf{\textsf{Jiahao Wang}}}
\date{\textbf{\textsf{January 2024}}}

\geometry{a4paper,hmargin=1.25in,vmargin=1in,headheight=13.6pt}
\graphicspath{{Figures/}}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{1.6pt}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let \bm=\relax}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\sffamily

%----------------------------------------------

%----------------------------------------------

\section*{\textsf{Section}}
Content \cite[Example 1.28]{GTM167}.

%----------------------------------------------

%----------------------------------------------

\newpage

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{GTM167} Morandi, P. (1996). \textit{Field and Galois theory} (\textit{Graduate Texts in Mathematics No. 167}). Springer-Verlag New York, Inc. \url{https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-4040-2}.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Notice that everything is written in Sans Serif. However, the "References" is written in Roman font. I'd like to change it for some consistency, is it possible to do so?

Comment: Or if anybody has an idea of making the "References" invisible. I can add another `\section*{References}`, which might be another approach if this works easier.

Answer (score 3):

You just need

```latex
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
```

And you can remove `\textsf` and `\sffamily` from your `.tex` file.